# How to use one button to run two different functions?

Tags: javascript

I have an image with several different overlays. The first overlay is visible and when a user clicks a button I want to hide the original overlay and display the overlay connected to that button. I have two separate bits of Javascript and they each work separately, but when put together they do not work.

I'm not sure how to get a button to do one function using onclick and the other one as well. I am newish to JavaScript so I am probably missing something simple. I created the second bit of script first using the event listener and then added the onclick later so as to show the original overlay.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'd-din_condensedregular';
    src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c256284620b85c4b8b6f684/t/5cf648197285b20001011026/1559644185350/d-dincondensed-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c256284620b85c4b8b6f684/t/5cf6481197a71f00013cfeaa/1559644177152/d-dincondensed-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

.hide {
z-index:2;
display: none;

}
.hidingsection{
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559688402/elke/map_base_1_r6fiqd.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
  width:1080px;
  height:653px;
background-color:#f3f4f4;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.hidingsection{z-index:0;}
.alertName{ text-align: center;
  background-color: #b2bb1e;
  padding: .6em .8em .8em;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: 'd-din_condensedregular';
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -.2em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  outline: 0;
  transition: .2s;
  will-change: transform;
}
.alertName:active {
  transform: scale(.9);

}
.buttons{display:flex; justify-content:space-around;}

.container{display:flex; flex-flow:column; justify-content: center;}

.hide img{
  width:1080px;
  height:653px;
}

.map img {
  width:1080px;
  height:653px;
}

#overlay{
  width:1080px;
  height:653px;
  display:block;
}
.default{display:none;}
  /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
  .hide img{
  width:325px;
  height:197px;
}

  .hidingsection{
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559671263/elke/imageedit_133_6444982912_1_hasrro.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
  width:325px;
  height:197px;
background-color:#f3f4f4;
  margin-left:0px;
}

  .alertName{ text-align: center;
  background-color: #b2bb1e;
  padding: .6em .8em .8em;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: 'd-din_condensedregular';
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -.2em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  outline: 0;
  transition: .2s;
  will-change: transform;
    font-size:7px;
}

}

  /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
   .hide img{
  width:670px;
  height:405px;
}

  .hidingsection{
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559686207/elke/map_base_jeg9zh.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
  width:670px;
  height:405px;
background-color:#f3f4f4;
  margin-left:0px;
}



}

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">

  <div class ="map">
<section class="hidingsection">
<div id = "overlay"><img src ="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559686870/elke/recreation_2000px_1_f2dh0s_eo0iuk.png"/>

<div class="hide schoolContent">

<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559669567/elke/schools_yes_2000px_rlsamn.png"/>

</div>
<div class ="hide recreationContent">
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559670471/elke/recreation_2000px_1_f2dh0s.png"/>

</div>

<div class="hide restaurantsContent">

<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559922796/elke/restaurants_2000px_1_diolpo_pnjkdt.png"/>

</div>

<div class="hide groceriesContent">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559670128/elke/groceries_2000px_hvr4f2.png"/>
  </div>

<div class="hide banksContent">

<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559670312/elke/comm_amenities_i4xgdk.png"/>

</div>


</section></div>

<div class="buttons"><div>

<button  class="alertName toggleBtn" name="schoolContent"  >SCHOOLS</button></div>

<div><button  class="alertName" name="recreationContent">RECREATION</button></div>

<div><button  class="alertName" name="restaurantsContent">RESTAURANTS</button></div>

<div><button  class="alertName" name="groceriesContent">GROCERY STORES</button>

</div>

<div><button  class="alertName" name="banksContent">COMMUNITY AMENITIES</button>

</div>


</div>
</div>
    <script>

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("overlay");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

}


var alertName = document.getElementsByClassName("alertName");


var myFunction = function() {

var hide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

for (var i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {

hide[i].style.display = "none";

}

var name = this.getAttribute("name");

var show = document.querySelector('.' + name);

if (show.style.display == "none") {

show.style.display = "block";

}

else {

show.style.display = "none";

}


};

for (var i = 0; i < alertName.length; i++) {

alertName[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);


}



</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I would like to end up with is the "overlay" div showing on load and being hidden on click while the selected div is shown on click. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do a combined function? function f3() { f1(); f2(); } and bind f3 to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by dynamically changing image src also works i did some modification to your code try it

```js
var srcs = {
        original: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559686870/elke/recreation_2000px_1_f2dh0s_eo0iuk.png",
        schoolContent: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559669567/elke/schools_yes_2000px_rlsamn.png",
        recreationContent: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559670471/elke/recreation_2000px_1_f2dh0s.png",
        restaurantsContent: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559922796/elke/restaurants_2000px_1_diolpo_pnjkdt.png",
        groceriesContent: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559670128/elke/groceries_2000px_hvr4f2.png",
        banksContent: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559670312/elke/comm_amenities_i4xgdk.png"
      };
      var alertName = document.getElementsByClassName("alertName");
      for (var i = 0; i < alertName.length; i++) {
        alertName[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          changecontent(this)
        })
      }

      function changecontent(ele) {
        var overlayimg = document.getElementById("overlayimage");
        if (overlayimg.src === srcs[ele.name]) {
          overlayimg.src = srcs["original"];
        } else {
          overlayimg.src = srcs[ele.name];
        }
      }
```

```css
 @font-face {
      font-family: 'd-din_condensedregular';
      src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c256284620b85c4b8b6f684/t/5cf648197285b20001011026/1559644185350/d-dincondensed-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c256284620b85c4b8b6f684/t/5cf6481197a71f00013cfeaa/1559644177152/d-dincondensed-webfont.woff') format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;

    }

    .hide {
      z-index: 2;
      display: none;

    }

    .hidingsection {
      background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559688402/elke/map_base_1_r6fiqd.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      width: 1080px;
      height: 653px;
      background-color: #f3f4f4;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .hidingsection {
      z-index: 0;
    }

    .alertName {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #b2bb1e;
      padding: .6em .8em .8em;
      border: none;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 5px;
      font-family: 'd-din_condensedregular';
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: inset 0 -.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      outline: 0;
      transition: .2s;
      will-change: transform;
    }

    .alertName:active {
      transform: scale(.9);

    }

    .buttons {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .hide img {
      width: 1080px;
      height: 653px;
    }

    .map img {
      width: 1080px;
      height: 653px;
    }

    #overlay {
      width: 1080px;
      height: 653px;
      display: block;
    }

    .default {
      display: none;
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      /* Styles */
      .hide img {
        width: 325px;
        height: 197px;
      }

      .hidingsection {
        background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559671263/elke/imageedit_133_6444982912_1_hasrro.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        width: 325px;
        height: 197px;
        background-color: #f3f4f4;
        margin-left: 0px;
      }

      .alertName {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #b2bb1e;
        padding: .6em .8em .8em;
        border: none;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 5px;
        font-family: 'd-din_condensedregular';
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        outline: 0;
        transition: .2s;
        will-change: transform;
        font-size: 7px;
      }

    }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      /* Styles */
      .hide img {
        width: 670px;
        height: 405px;
      }

      .hidingsection {
        background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559686207/elke/map_base_jeg9zh.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        width: 670px;
        height: 405px;
        background-color: #f3f4f4;
        margin-left: 0px;
      }



    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="map">
      <section class="hidingsection">
        <div id="overlay"><img id="overlayimage" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnu8yyawg/image/upload/v1559686870/elke/recreation_2000px_1_f2dh0s_eo0iuk.png" />
        </div>
      </section>
      </div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <div>

          <button class="alertName toggleBtn" name="schoolContent">SCHOOLS</button></div>

        <div><button class="alertName" name="recreationContent">RECREATION</button></div>

        <div><button class="alertName" name="restaurantsContent">RESTAURANTS</button></div>

        <div><button class="alertName" name="groceriesContent">GROCERY STORES</button>

        </div>

        <div><button class="alertName" name="banksContent">COMMUNITY AMENITIES</button>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to give each overlay some sort of `data-` attribute so you can select it. Then, you can give each button a function that will both hide all the other overlays, and show the one you need. You do this by creating a new function that will call the other two functions that you need:

```js
const showDivWithDataOverlay = dataOverlayValue => document
    .querySelector(`div[data-overlay="${dataOverlayValue}"]`)
    .style.display = 'inline-block';

const hideAllDataOverlayDivs = () => document
  .querySelectorAll('div')
  .forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none')

const showOnly = dataOverlayToShow => {
  hideAllDataOverlayDivs();
  showDivWithDataOverlay(dataOverlayToShow);
}

showOnly('a');
```

```html
<div data-overlay="a">a</div>
<div data-overlay="b">b</div>
<div data-overlay="c">c</div>

<button onclick="showOnly('a')">a</button>
<button onclick="showOnly('b')">b</button>
<button onclick="showOnly('c')">c</button>
```